# Why the IDispose pattern is implemented in this way?

Tags: c#, .net

Below is code from the source below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

```
using System;

class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
    // To detect redundant calls
    private bool _disposed = false;

    ~BaseClass() => Dispose(false);

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
        }

        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
        // TODO: set large fields to null.

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

And the source says sth about why

```
if (disposing) {
   // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
}
```

is needed:

> If the method call comes from a finalizer, only the code that frees unmanaged resources should execute. The implementer is responsible for ensuring that the false path doesn't interact with managed objects that may have been reclaimed. This is important because the order in which the garbage collector destroys managed objects during finalization is non-deterministic.

But I have a question, when the Finalize method of BaseClass is called, all its fields which contains managed objects will still in the heap, as the BaseClass object itself must survive the garbage collection and gets prompted to another generation, and when finalizable objects get promoted, any object referred to by its fields also get promoted because they must continue to live too.
so the managed object referenced by field of BaseClass won't be reclaimed by GC. Can anybody provide a concrete example why it needs to be implemented in this way?

Comment: Because finalizers are run on a separate thread, and the finalizer could take any amount of time. The GC promotes the object to the next generation to get it "out of the way" and continue with GC even as finalizers may still be running. That does mean child objects stay alive as well, yes -- finalizers are costly and should be kept to a minimum. Ideally a finalizable object has no children at all and simply represents an unmanaged resource only (like a handle).

Comment: Just to add an additional note on what @JeroenMostert says: a *lot* of this mess comes from people trying to do too much in one place, especially when inheritance is concerned; rather than adding unmanaged resources in some sub-class, a far easier to support approach is to write a class where the *sole reason for existence* is to manage that handle/whatever - probably `sealed`, with a really simple finalizer and Dispose - and then in the new sub-class just *have a reference* to that other type; the type in the inheritance model: never gets a finalizer, and has a simple Dispose.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in a *finalizer* (rather than `Dispose()`) - i.e. `disposing` is `false`, you simply shouldn't assume *anything* about the state other objects. **You don't know what order the finalizers will be executed in**. There is no deterministic order and none can be offered (think "cycles"). And besides: *that isn't the point*. If you wanted to cleanup *managed* resources, you should have done that in `Dispose()`. If somebody failed to call `Dispose()`, then *that person has a bug*, not you. You should only talk to *unmanaged* resources in a finalizer. And frankly, accessing genuinely unmanaged resources is *incredibly* rare, so in reality: you almost never need any of this complexity.

Comment: but all the field object are alive in the heap when the instance's Finalize method run, I don't assume this, this is he rule,could you provide an concrete code example, thank you

Comment: @slowjams they're *probably* still on the heap but you don't know that they're alive - they are now the undead, and if '80s horror shows taught me anything: you don't mess with the undead. They might *already have been finalized*, but you're missing the point: **you're not meant to try touching them**. They are now in an undefined state. I have provided a concrete code example of not touching other objects from a finalizer, but it turns out that "not doing something" took zero lines of code. You are asserting that they're alive and well: you don't know that to be true, and shouldn't assume it.

Comment: @slowjams if you mean "the memory hasn't been reclaimed yet", then fine - but that doesn't change a thing: **you're not meant to look**. The *only* thing you should do in a finalizer is release unmanaged resources owned by the **current** instance. Nothing else. I would also permit static logging and static counter (interlocked) increment/decrement usage for debug purposes in a `#if DEBUG` build.